# DomPDF - Changing the point/pixel ratio

Tags: php, pdf-generation, dompdf

I'm trying to use [DomPDF](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) to generate a PDF out of some HTML. I need the page to be 20mm x 20mm, so I use the following:

```
CPDF_Adapter::$PAPER_SIZES['my_square_page'] = array(0, 0, 566.929134, 566.929134);
$dompdf->set_paper('my_square_page','portrait');
```

It works properly, if I check the PDF properties the size is ok. The HTML that will appear in the PDF has a container `div` of 490x490px. This size cannot be changed, as the elements inside that `div` are absolutely positioned.

The problem, then, is that in the generated PDF the `div` **does not cover the entire page**. I've tried setting the DPI, using different values in

```
def("DOMPDF_DPI", 150);
```

But it does not seem to make any difference at all. The output I get is this (gray borders are from the PDF reader):

[image]

I've tried setting the `width` and `height` of `body` and `html` in the CSS of the content, but it does not work.

You can check the [source code of my sample case here](http://pastebin.com/G4j4CQu8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Looks like the line

```
def("DOMPDF_DPI", 150);
```

does not actually do anything. I did change the `dompdf_config.custom.inc` file and then it worked. Added this:

```
define("DOMPDF_DPI", 62.230);
```

But now the images look too big :S

[image]

Comment: It seems that controlling the size of `background-image`'s is pretty difficult under these circumnstances. However, using `<img>` seems to work properly, so there we go.

Comment: Right now the only way to adjust the size of the background is to modify the DPI (as you have seen). At some point we will implement the background-size CSS property, which gives you much finer control. Until then, however, it's best to resize the image to fit your document.

Comment: Also, FYI, PDF documents are rendered at (essentially) 72 DPI. So to get more of a one-to-one correspondence between your HTML and your PDF you should set DOMPDF_DPI to 72. And, as I said, resize your background to fit the space.